# python-selenium: execute_script vs execute_async

Tags: python, selenium

is not very clear to me the difference between `execute_script` and `execute_async_script` in selenium.

given this example in python-selenium, into a pytest function:

```
driver.get(url)

js = '''
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

video.onplaying=function() {
  return "play";
};
'''

video_play = driver.execute_script(js)
assert video_play == "play"
```

the result is:

```
E       AssertionError: assert None == 'play'
```

what am i missing? should i use execute_async and an async/await function in js? could you point me at some examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use async script for this.

```
driver.get(url)

js = '''
var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

video.onplaying=function() {
  callback ("play");
};

setTimeout(function(){
  callback("notplayed");
}, 2000);
'''

video_play = driver.execute_async_script(js)
assert video_play == "play"
```

What above does is that it waits for 2 secs max for the playback to happen if it doesn't then `notplayed` is returned.

Do remember that the call will not return until the script has finished. So don't think that you can execute some other code after the async script. Until the callback or async timeout, the code will be stuck at `execute_async_script`